# Entity framework order by dynamic input or default by id

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Does anyone has an idea how can I do the following:

I have this code:

sortOrder is user input

```
db.Table.OrderBy(s => sortOrder == "name" ? s.Table.Name : s.Id).ToList();
```

And get following error:

```
Error   CS0173  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'int'
```

And if I set s.Id.ToString() then it will no longer be ordered by ascending numbers instead it's a string and won't order it properly, is there a way for me to convert function so it accepts numbers? It almost feels like bug because switch statement default accepts Id even though cases are strings

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use LINQ Dynamic, there are 2 libraries to know.

#### System.Linq.Dynamic

This library is free and open source.

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/

The library has his own syntax but is very easy to use:

```
myDataSource.OrderBy("someColumnName descending")
```

#### C# Eval Expression

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [C# Eval Expression](https://eval-expression.net/linq-dynamic)

The library is not free, but you can do pretty much any dynamic LINQ using the same syntax as C#.

So you will be able to build a string to evaluate and the library will do the rest for you.

Here is an online example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oxSl3s

```
var customersList2 = context.Customers
    .Include(x => x.Invoices)
    .WhereDynamic(c => "c.Invoices.Count > 0")
    .OrderByDescendingDynamic(c => "c.Invoices.Count")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you I will take a look into it